# How to reload the page while moving from tab bar in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

Here after running the application i had clicked on cart in tab bar at that time there was no items added in cart so it shown your shopping cart is empty but after adding items in cart then I clicked on cart icon on tab bar also it is showing like as in previous and the cart page was not reloading can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

I had used this code in my home view controller

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        if tabBarIndex == 1 {
            let  navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
            let secondViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! AddToCartViewController
            secondViewController.firstTimeTableSkip = true
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        }
    }
```

in my cart view controller I used this code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if firstLoginCheck == true {
        checkOutButton.isHidden = false
        checkOutButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        if conditonCheck == true || conditonCheck == nil{
        checkOutButton.isHidden = true
        checkOutButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        tableDetails.isHidden = true
        emptyView.isHidden = true
        tableDetails.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        loginCheck = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "CustomerLogin")
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        emptyView.isHidden = true
        if loginCheck == 1 {
            let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "CustomerLoginToken")
            self.customerKeyToken = token!
            print(self.customerKeyToken!)
            if itemCode != nil {
                self.customerAddToCartItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(cartApi: customerAddtoCartApi)
       customerCartItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(cartApi: customerCartApi)
            }
            else {
                customerCartItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(cartApi: customerCartApi)
            }
        }else if (loginCheck == 0) || (loginCheck == nil) {
            if let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_token")  {
                self.key = token as? String
                let defaultValue = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "MenuButton") as? String
                if (defaultValue == "Tab" && itemCode == nil) {
                    check = true
           cartCountApiDownloadJsonWithURL(cartCountApi: getCartApi)
                }
            } else {
                gettingKeyFromJsonWithURL(keyApi: keygettingApi)
            }
            if itemCode != nil && key != nil {
                self.PostingKeyFromJsonWithURL(PostingApi: postingKeyApi)
            }
            if key != nil {
                cartCountApiDownloadJsonWithURL(cartCountApi: getCartApi)
                emptyView.isHidden = true
            }
            }
        }
```

[image: Here is my home page][image]

Comment: You can put code in `viewWillAppear` that you want to be reload.

Comment: already having code in cart page but I checked now that the condition for bool was failing how to pass data while clicking on tab bar @iPatel

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I had added my code @HakikatSingh

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using notification or delegate or relevant, `viewWillApear()` method will be more suitable for reloading views. Just put your code which you want to be reloaded into `viewWillApear()`

Answer (score 0):

you can set notification whenever your cart view will appear and set method for reloading when notification fire.

Comment: already I placed code in view will appear but what happens here is first after checking condition in view will appear then the tab bar delegate was calling so it returning nil so its failing @Rakesh Patel

Answer (score 0):

Check the part of code where you are setting the badge icon count for "Cart". You need to persist the cart data in the same code flow.

Since you are having a boolean check in viewWillAppear, retrieve the cart data before performing the check.
It is a good idea to have CoreData for local persistence in case you are not syncing it with any server.

Comment: already I placed code in view will appear but what happens here after clicking on tab bar cart icon it is first checking condition in view will appear which is in cart page then the tab bar delegate was calling which is in home page so it returning nil so its failing @TinselBoy